# Initializing variables in a class hierarchy

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I got assigned the task to clean up a class hierarchy, but I'm stuck in a bit of a rut. I'm now left with something that roughly looks like this:

```
class Base
{
Base() = 0;

function1();
   ...
function5();

protected:

int variable1_;
   ...
int variable10_;
}; 

class DerivedOne
   : public Base
{
   DerivedOne() = 0;

   function6();
      ...
   function10();

 protected:

   int variable11_;
      ...
   int variable20_;
};

class DerivedTwo
   : public DerivedOne
{
    DerivedTwo()
       : DerivedOne() 
    {
       ... Fill variable1_ to variable25_ with data read from file ...
       variable1_ = ...
    }

    function11();
      ...
    function15();

  private:

    int variable21_;
      ...
    int variable25_;
};
```

So 25 variable are assigned their values in DerivedTwo, making it easy to make a mistake. When another class inherits from DerivedOne, it's almost certain that that person will forget to initialize one of the variables.

I've been playing around with different ways of designing this hierarchy, but nothing really feels right.

I understand it's difficult to say something concrete without knowing what these classes actually do, but I would be interested in knowing if there is something fundamental wrong with this design, or if I have overlooked some elegant way of initializing all the variables.

Comment: why not initializing the variables in one of those classes with their specific non-default constructor (passing the filename for instance, sharing the handle or whatever) ? Any reason not to do it?

Comment: Other classes that inherit from DerivedOne will not initialize the values from a file, so the Base classes should be more general. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the post.

Comment: Can you post real code? What is `Base() = 0`?  What is `DerivedTwo() : DerivedOne()`? you know `DerivedOne()` is called automatically right?

Comment: Do you need to read a file in the constructor ?  What do you do if reading goes wrong or if you can't open the file:  return an empty object ?  Or an inconsistent one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle in derivation is that base object is constructed first, and the derived afterwards.  This requires the Base and DerivedOne constructor to produce a valid object on its own.

When constructing DerivedTwo, your code makes this clear:

```
   DerivedTwo()
       : DerivedOne()  // First the base object constructor is called, before anything else 
   {
       // then remaining initialisation, after DerivedOne() was created
   }
```

So each class should at least initialise its own variables to an initial valid state that its own functions can handle in a consistent manner.

```
Base() : variable1_(/*default value here*/), variable10_(/*default value here*/) {}
Base(int v1, int v10) : variable1_(v1), variable10_(v10) {} // for convenience
```

One derived class could overwrite variables of its base class afterwards.  It would of course be safer and more elegant to use getters/setters, but its ok.

If you adopt this design,  if one subderived class forgets to initialise a variable one of its parents, this should not lead to a catastrophee because at least the base object is initialised in a decent manner.

Now the problem is that you also initiate your DerivedTwo by reading a file.  Remember, first Base is created, then DerivedOne, and then only DerivedTwo reads the values.  What happen when the file cannot be read or is unconsistent ?  You might end up having an inconsistent object, unless your throw an exception. So you have to manage this and make sure that DerivedTwo is in a stable state:

```
   DerivedTwo()
       : DerivedOne()  // First the base object constructor is called 
   {
       // then initialise all own members to a consitent state
       // then try to read the file and manage potential errors 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll keep all of this in mind when redesigning.

Answer (score 0):

Each class should be responsible for initializing its own data members.  As you identified, it is dangerous for `Base` to assume that `DerivedX` will initialize its data members.  So...

`Base` should initialize `variable1_` ... `variable10_`

`DerivedOne` should initialize `variable11_` ... `variable20_`

`DerivedTwo` should initialize `variable21_` ... `variable25_`

...and so on.

Of course, this doesn't address the question of why the classes are laid out in such a fashion...